# Add Item in Firebase Database Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to Add something into Firebase Database, but it does not work.

In My ViewController.m, I think a problem from here :

```
- (IBAction)addButtonDidTouch:(id)sender {
UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Grocery Item" message:@"Add an Item" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];


UIAlertAction *saveAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Save" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * _Nonnull action) {

        UITextField *textField = alert.textFields[0];
        GroceryItem *groceryItem = [[GroceryItem alloc]initWithName:textField.text byUser:self.user.email completed:false withKey:@""];
        Firebase *groceryItemRef = [[Firebase alloc ]childByAppendingPath:textField.text.lowercaseString];
        [groceryItemRef setValue:groceryItem.toAnyObject];



}];
  UIAlertAction *cancelAlert = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * _Nonnull action) {
      NSLog(@"You was cancel");
  }];
[alert addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler:^(UITextField * _Nonnull textField) {

        [alert addAction:saveAction];

        [alert addAction:cancelAlert];

}];
[self presentViewController:alert animated:true completion:nil]; }
```

When Tap Button Add and type text , then I tap SAVE..it not work 
Please watch my images [image: HERE]

Comment: Instead of posting an image of text, can you please post the actual text? That makes the question easier to scan and searchable.

Comment: I sincerely apologize for the careless on.
I want to find documentation about Obj-C use FirebaseDatabase , the demo I found I could not Build them on my iphone to see how it work, so I was looking through documents on Swift and convert them through Obj-C it is very difficult for me in those days, and I absolutely can not understand how to use Firebase to update data in real time.

Hope you can help me find a standard document so I can learn, including: it can be a video or demo so I can run on my iphone.

I am extremely thankful for his help! Good health and all good things.